# Why is ls sorting Chinese filenames by length?

Tags: ls, sort, macos, locale, unicode

I've run into a bit of a weird behaviour that I don't fully understand with `ls` and Chinese filenames. I'm running macOS 13.6.1 with SIP enabled (no core OS modifications), MacPorts installed, and US English as the primary language.

First, run this little script in a blank folder to make some test files:

```py
import random

random.seed(42)

for i in range(30):
    n = random.randrange(3, 8)
    fn = "".join(random.choice("一二三") for _ in range(n))
    open(fn, "w")
```

This makes 30 files named with random combinations of the characters 一二三 (one, two, three).

Next, I run `ls -l` on my Mac (version "macOS 13.5" according to the manpage):

```
% ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 brx  staff  164 Nov 25 02:41 test.py
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一一三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三三一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三三三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三一三一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三二一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一二一一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一二三二一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二一一三三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二三二三二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二二一一二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二二三二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一一一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二三三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 一二一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 三一一二二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二三三二三二二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 二三二一二二一
```

The files are clearly sorted *by filename length*, but are otherwise *not sorted* within identical lengths, as if `ls` is treating all Chinese characters as being exactly equivalent.

`LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8` (and no `LC_*` variable is set), so maybe this is just a problem with the English sorting?

```
% LANG=zh_CN.utf-8 ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 brx  staff  164 11 25 02:41 test.py
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一一三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三三一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三三三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三一三一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三二一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一二一一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一二三二一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二一一三三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二三二三二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二二一一二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二二三二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三二一一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三二一一一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一三二三三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 一二一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 三一一二二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二三三二三二二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 11 25 02:41 二三二一二二一
```

Right, maybe this is just the Mac built-in `ls` being crappy; let's try GNU Coreutils (from MacPorts, `ls (GNU coreutils) 9.4`):

```
% gls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff 164 Nov 25 02:41 test.py
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一一三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三三一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三三三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三一三一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三二一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一二一一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一二三二一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一一三三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二三二三二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二二一一二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二二三二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一一一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二三三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一二一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三一一二二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二三三二三二二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二三二一二二一
% LANG=zh_CN.utf-8 gls -l
总计 4
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff 164 1125日 02:41 test.py
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一一三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三三一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三三三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三一三一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三二一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一二一一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一二三二一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二一一三三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二三二三二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二二一一二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二二三二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三二一一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三二一一一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一三二三三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 一二一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 三一一二二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二三三二三二二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 1125日 02:41 二三二一二二一
```

Besides the *humourously* broken date display from GNU Coreutils, nothing changes. The only thing that kinda seems to work is `C.utf-8`:

```
% LANG=C.utf-8 ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--@ 1 brx  staff  164 Nov 25 02:41 test.py
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ???????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ???????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ???????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ?????????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx  staff    0 Nov 25 02:41 ??????????????????
% LANG=C.utf-8 gls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff 164 Nov 25 02:41 test.py
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一一三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二一一一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一三二三三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一二一一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一二一三二三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 一二三二一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三一一二二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三一三一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三三一三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三三三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三二一三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三二三一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 三二二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一一一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一一三三二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一三三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二一二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二三三二三二二
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二三二一二二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二三二三二三
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二二一一二一
-rw-r--r--+ 1 brx staff   0 Nov 25 02:41 二二三二一二
```

What's going on here? Are locales broken on my Mac?

EDIT: To clarify the *expected* behaviour: I would expect `ls` to sort the characters in any reasonable sorting order; some reasonable orders would be Unicode codepoint (一, 三, 二), numerical or stroke-count order (一, 二, 三), or Pinyin order (二, 三, 一, corresponding to "er, san, yi").

Some extra information to answer comments (in `en_US.UTF-8` locale):

- the order stays the same when piped to `sort` or `gsort` with or without `-u`.
- there is actually no C.utf-8 locale on my system which explains why I get the same output as in the C locale there, an order by byte value and each of the byte rendered as `?`.
- `expr '一二三' '<' '三一二'`, `expr '一二三' '>' '三一二'`, `expr '一二三' = '三一二'` return 1, 0 and 0 respectively whether that's with macos `expr` or GNU `expr`.
- `perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strcoll@ARGV' -- '一' '二'` outputs `-140` whether that's with the `perl` shipped with macos or MacPorts.
- `perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strcoll@ARGV' -- '一一' '二'` outputs `19968`
- the encodings of those characters look like `$'\344\270\200\344\270\200\344\270\211'` for `一一三` as reported by `gls` in the `C` locale, so it looks like they are properly encoded in UTF-8.
- the output of `perl -MPOSIX -le 'print unpack "H*", strxfrm$_ for @ARGV' -- '一' '一一' '二'` is:

  ```
  303034323030303030346c32
  30303432303034323030303030346c3230346c32
  303034323030303030346e3e
  ```
- the output of `perl -MPOSIX -le 'print "$_\t" . unpack "H*", strxfrm$_ for <*>'` is

  ```
  一一三一  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3230346c3b30346c32
  一一三   3030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3230346c3b
  一三三二三一    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346c32
  一三二一一一一   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346e3e30346c3230346c3230346c3230346c32
  一三二一一一二   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346e3e30346c3230346c3230346c3230346e3e
  一三二一  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346e3e30346c32
  一三二三三三一   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346c3b30346c3b30346c32
  一三二三三 30303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346c3b
  一三二   3030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346c3b30346e3e
  一二一一三三    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346e3e30346c3230346c3230346c3b30346c3b
  一二一三二三三   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346e3e30346c3230346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346c3b
  一二三二一一    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3230346e3e30346c3b30346e3e30346c3230346c32
  三一一二二二三   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346c3230346c3230346e3e30346e3e30346e3e30346c3b
  三一三一一 30303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346c3230346c3b30346c3230346c32
  三三一三  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346c3b30346c3230346c3b
  三三一   3030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346c3b30346c32
  三三三三  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346c3b30346c3b30346c3b
  三二一三二 30303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346e3e30346c3230346c3b30346e3e
  三二三一  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346c32
  三二二三  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346c3b30346e3e30346e3e30346c3b
  二一一一  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3230346c3230346c32
  二一一三三二    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3230346c3230346c3b30346c3b30346e3e
  二一三三  303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3230346c3b30346c3b
  二一二   3030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3230346e3e
  二三三二三二二   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3b30346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346e3e30346e3e
  二三二一二二一   303034323030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3b30346e3e30346c3230346e3e30346e3e30346c32
  二三二三二三    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346c3b30346e3e30346c3b30346e3e30346c3b
  二二一一二一    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346e3e30346c3230346c3230346e3e30346c32
  二二三二一二    3030343230303432303034323030343230303432303034323030303030346e3e30346e3e30346c3b30346e3e30346c3230346e3e
  test.py   303033563030333830303355303033563030314d303033523030335f30303030303033563030333830303355303033563030314d303033523030335f
  ```

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149934/discussion-on-question-by-nneonneo-why-is-ls-sorting-chinese-filenames-by-length) since the isue seems to have been resolved and the relevant information now added to either the question or an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll notice that among the strings of same length, there appears to be a relative order of those characters, so they're not totally treated as being equivalent. It's not like the  which have no defined order in GNU libc locales and where you get random order there in most UTF-8 locales such as your `en_US.UTF-8`:

```
$ ls -1





























test.py
$ ls -1 | sort -u




test.py
```

What you got is the same kind of sorting order one gets when sorting strings made of characters that have the same *primary collation weight* but different subsequent weights.

For instance, in most locales, `e`, `E`, `É` and `é` have the same primary weights for good reason. This is how `Stéphane` or `STÉPHANE` can sort before `Stephen` even though `Stephane` sorts before `Stéphane` for instance.

```
EeE
eeé
eéE
éée
Eeee
eeée
Eeéé
eéEe
éEEé
éEée
ééeé
éééé
eéEéé
éEeéE
éeéee
EEeeEe
eEeeéé
EeeééE
eEéEee
EEéEeE
EéEéEé
eééEée
eEeéEéé
eéEeeee
eéEeeeE
EéEeEEe
eéEééée
EééEéEE
éeeEEEé
```

(note that all of `e`, `E` and `é` have the same primary weight, `e` and `E` also have the same secondary  weight)

From your result of `strxfrm()`, which looks like it's actually ASCII text which we can decode to:

```
一一三          004200420042000004l204l204l;
一三二          004200420042000004l204l;04n>
三三一          004200420042000004l;04l;04l2
二一二          004200420042000004n>04l204n>
一一三一        0042004200420042000004l204l204l;04l2
一三二一        0042004200420042000004l204l;04n>04l2
三三一三        0042004200420042000004l;04l;04l204l;
三三三三        0042004200420042000004l;04l;04l;04l;
三二三一        0042004200420042000004l;04n>04l;04l2
三二二三        0042004200420042000004l;04n>04n>04l;
二一一一        0042004200420042000004n>04l204l204l2
二一三三        0042004200420042000004n>04l204l;04l;
一三二三三      00420042004200420042000004l204l;04n>04l;04l;
三一三一一      00420042004200420042000004l;04l204l;04l204l2
三二一三二      00420042004200420042000004l;04n>04l204l;04n>
一三三二三一    004200420042004200420042000004l204l;04l;04n>04l;04l2
一二一一三三    004200420042004200420042000004l204n>04l204l204l;04l;
一二三二一一    004200420042004200420042000004l204n>04l;04n>04l204l2
二一一三三二    004200420042004200420042000004n>04l204l204l;04l;04n>
二三二三二三    004200420042004200420042000004n>04l;04n>04l;04n>04l;
二二一一二一    004200420042004200420042000004n>04n>04l204l204n>04l2
二二三二一二    004200420042004200420042000004n>04n>04l;04n>04l204n>
一三二一一一一  0042004200420042004200420042000004l204l;04n>04l204l204l204l2
一三二一一一二  0042004200420042004200420042000004l204l;04n>04l204l204l204n>
一三二三三三一  0042004200420042004200420042000004l204l;04n>04l;04l;04l;04l2
一二一三二三三  0042004200420042004200420042000004l204n>04l204l;04n>04l;04l;
三一一二二二三  0042004200420042004200420042000004l;04l204l204n>04n>04n>04l;
二三三二三二二  0042004200420042004200420042000004n>04l;04l;04n>04l;04n>04n>
二三二一二二一  0042004200420042004200420042000004n>04l;04n>04l204n>04n>04l2
```

you can see that `0042` is likely its representation of the primary weight of those 一二三 characters and it's the same for all 3. Then there's likely a 0000 separator and by the look of it only one additional (secondary) weight which is `04n>`, `04l;` and `04l2` for 二 (U+4E8C), 三 (U+4E09), and 一 (U+4E00) respectively¹.

Why their collation order is defined like that I don't know. It's not the case on GNU systems where in most locales, the primary weights for U+4E00 to U+9FA5 are different and in sequence of their Unicode code point. Nor is it the case on FreeBSD 12.4-RELEASE-p5 at least.

It's also possible (even likely) that what we're seeing above is that those characters have an undefined primary weight and the `0042` we're seeing is the secondary weight. Which would explain why we seem to see only two weights per character in the `strxfrm()` result.

That means that in the first pass of comparing strings that happen to contain those characters, those characters are just ignored for the purpose of comparison. That's normally the case for blank or punctuation  characters where you don't want them to have a strong influence on the order. For instance `foo-bar` would sort between `fooargh` and `football` and the secondary and further weights of `-` would only be used to determine the relative order of `foo-bar` and `foo+bar` for instance.

Apple might have decided that since not everybody agrees on the order of those characters, we might as well ignore them.

---

<sup>¹ Interesting to note (though it doesn't shed any light on this issue) is that 19968 is 0x4E00 suggesting the last weight is based on the code point. `04l2`, `04l;`, `04n>` and even `0042` in the strxfrm strings seem to be numbers in some sort of base 64 with 0123...lmno as the digits corresponding to those weights offset by 258 (42 in that base).</sup>

Comment: @PhilipCouling https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_orders is a long read.

Answer (score 1):

I found out where macOS stores locale files, in `/usr/share/locale`, and to my surprise this is how the `zh_CN.UTF-8` locale is defined:

```
% ls -la /usr/share/locale/zh_CN.UTF-8
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    8 root  wheel   256 Oct 12 04:10 .
drwxr-xr-x  209 root  wheel  6688 Oct 12 04:10 ..
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    28 Oct 12 04:10 LC_COLLATE -> ../la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    17 Oct 12 04:10 LC_CTYPE -> ../UTF-8/LC_CTYPE
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel    96 Oct 12 04:10 LC_MESSAGES
-r--r--r--    2 root  wheel    36 Oct 12 04:10 LC_MONETARY
lrwxr-xr-x    1 root  wheel    25 Oct 12 04:10 LC_NUMERIC -> ../zh_CN.eucCN/LC_NUMERIC
-r--r--r--    2 root  wheel   408 Oct 12 04:10 LC_TIME
```

`LC_COLLATE` is symlinked to `/usr/share/locale/la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE`. This file is just over 2KB in size, and while it is a binary file (rather than the textual format used by some other systems), it's pretty clearly defining collation for just 256 bytes:

```
% xxd /usr/share/locale/la_LN.US-ASCII/LC_COLLATE
00000000: 312e 3141 0a00 0000 0000 0101 0102 0000  1.1A............
00000010: 0102 ffff fefe 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002 0000 0002 0000  ................
00000030: 0003 0000 0003 0000 0004 0000 0004 0000  ................
00000040: 0005 0000 0005 0000 0006 0000 0006 0000  ................
00000050: 0007 0000 0007 0000 0008 0000 0008 0000  ................
00000060: 0009 0000 0009 0000 000a 0000 000a 0000  ................
00000070: 000b 0000 000b 0000 000c 0000 000c 0000  ................
00000080: 000d 0000 000d 0000 000e 0000 000e 0000  ................
00000090: 000f 0000 000f 0000 0010 0000 0010 0000  ................
...
00000760: 00e9 0000 00e9 0000 00ea 0000 00ea 0000  ................
00000770: 00eb 0000 00eb 0000 00ec 0000 00ec 0000  ................
00000780: 00ed 0000 00ed 0000 00ee 0000 00ee 0000  ................
00000790: 00ef 0000 00ef 0000 00f0 0000 00f0 0000  ................
000007a0: 00f1 0000 00f1 0000 00f2 0000 00f2 0000  ................
000007b0: 00f3 0000 00f3 0000 00f4 0000 00f4 0000  ................
000007c0: 00f5 0000 00f5 0000 00f6 0000 00f6 0000  ................
000007d0: 00f7 0000 00f7 0000 00f8 0000 00f8 0000  ................
000007e0: 00f9 0000 00f9 0000 00fa 0000 00fa 0000  ................
000007f0: 00fb 0000 00fb 0000 00fc 0000 00fc 0000  ................
00000800: 00fd 0000 00fd 0000 00fe 0000 00fe 0000  ................
00000810: 00ff 0000 00ff 0000 0100 0000 0100 0000  ................
00000820: 0101 0000 0101                           ......
```

So the problem seems to be that macOS simply does not define collation ordering for any Chinese characters at all (or really anything beyond the first 256 codepoints), even in Chinese locales.